I get an error when installing B2B Store via b2b-commerce-on-lightning-quickstart on the convert-examples-to-sfdx.sh step
I am following the instructions on this repo readme: [b2b-commerce-on-lightning-quickstart][1]
And I have problem running the script "convert-examples-to-sfdx.sh". The erros is:

/c/Program Files/sf/bin/../client/bin/sf.cmd: line 1: @echo: command not found
/c/Program Files/sf/bin/../client/bin/sf.cmd: line 2: setlocal: command not found
/c/Program Files/sf/bin/../client/bin/sf.cmd: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token (' /c/Program Files/sf/bin/../client/bin/sf.cmd: line 4: if not "%SF_REDIRECTED%"=="1" if exist "%LOCALAPPDA

I've read about different similar problems in stackoverflow and most of them propose that the problem has something to do with line endings. I am working on win and I've tried converting windows line endings of files with the VSCode editor to LF and it didn't work. I also configured git's autoclr to false in order to check out the code again. Now I think all files have LF as endings but the problem still occurs.
When I run the commands on the VSCode PS terminal line by line the commands work. The problem only occurs when you try to execute them as a script.
I've created a single file called "test_single_cmd.sh"
witjh this only command:
sfdx force:mdapi:convert -r ../examples/checkout-main

It gives the same error.
/c/Program Files/sf/bin/../client/bin/sf.cmd: line 1: @echo: command not found

Could you please rpovide some help on this?
Thank you in advance.
[1]: https://github.com/forcedotcom/b2b-commerce-on-lightning-quickstart/tree/master/sfdx
